# I cannot resolve the errors with attachInterrupt() (error: invalid use of non-static member function)

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, interrupt, compilation-errors

I have been trying for days to get this code to work, but I cannot find a solution. Can anyone please help me find what I am missing here?

**My sketch:**

```
#include <ControlInterrupt.h>

const int commonPin = 2;
const int buttonPins[] = {4,5,6,7,8};

ControlInterrupt controlInterrupt(commonPin, buttonPins);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  controlInterrupt.configureCommon(); // Setup pins for  interrupt
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(commonPin), controlInterrupt.pressInterrupt, FALLING);
  controlInterrupt.begin();
}

void loop() {
  // Empty
}
```

**.h**

```
/*
  ControlInterrupt.h - A library for handling multiple buttons using a single interrupt.
                       This is done by using an interrupt pin effectively as the ground,
                       eliminating the need for additional components.
  Authors: Svizel_pritula 05/05/2019
           TheCodeGeek 01/13/2024
*/
#ifndef ControlInterrupt_h
#define ControlInterrupt_h
#include <Arduino.h>
class ControlInterrupt
{
public:
  ControlInterrupt(int commonPin, int buttonPins[]);
  void begin();
  void pressInterrupt();
  void configureCommon();
  void configureDistinct();
  //void getCommand(int button);

private:
  int _commonPin;
  //int _arrLength;
  int _buttonPins[];
};
#endif
```

**.cpp**

```
/*
  ControlInterrupt.h - A library for handling multiple buttons using a single interrupt.
                       This is done by using an interrupt pin effectively as the ground,
                       eliminating the need for additional components.
  Authors: Svizel_pritula 05/05/2019
           TheCodeGeek 01/13/2024
*/
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ControlInterrupt.h>

unsigned long lastFire;

ControlInterrupt::ControlInterrupt(int commonPin, int buttonPins[])
//, String commandOrder[]
{
  _commonPin = commonPin;
  _arrLength = sizeof(buttonPins);
  _buttonPins[arrLength] = buttonPins;
  //_commandOrder[arrLength] = commandOrder;

  lastFire = 0;
}


void ControlInterrupt::begin()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void ControlInterrupt::pressInterrupt()
{ // ISR
  if (millis() - lastFire < 200)
  { // Debounce
    return;
  }
  lastFire = millis();

  configureDistinct(); // Setup  pins for testing individual buttons

  for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(buttonPins)/sizeof(int)); i++)
  { // Test each button for press
    if (!digitalRead(_buttonPins[i]))
    {
      getCommand(i);
    }
  }

  configureCommon(); // Return to original  state
}

void ControlInterrupt::configureCommon()
{
  pinMode(_commonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);

  for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(buttonPins)/sizeof(int)); i++)
  {
    pinMode(_buttonPins[i], OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(_buttonPins[i], LOW);
  }
}

void ControlInterrupt::configureDistinct()
{
  pinMode(_commonPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(_commonPin, LOW);

  for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(buttonPins)/sizeof(int)); i++)
  {
    pinMode(_buttonPins[i], INPUT_PULLUP);
  }
}

void ControlInterrupt::getCommand(int button)
//String ControlInterrupt::getCommand(int button)
{               // Our handler
  String label; // This stores the string to print when controls are used

  Serial.print(button + 1);
  Serial.print(": ");
  switch (button)
  {
  case 0:
    // statement
    label = "UP";
    break;
  case 1:
    // statement
    label = "DOWN";
    break;
  case 2:
    // statement
    label = "CLEAR";
    break;
  case 3:
    // statement
    label = "BACK";
    break;
  case 4:
    // statement
    label = "LEFT";
    break;
  case 5:
    // statement
    label = "ENTER";
    break;
  case 6:
    // statement
    label = "RIGHT";
    break;
  default:
    // statement
    break;
  }
  Serial.print(label);
  //return label;
}
```

Comment: It's all based on the code that I found here: https://projecthub.arduino.cc/Svizel_pritula/10-buttons-using-1-interrupt-6e0896

Comment: Please edit your post to show the error message you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is covered in my post [here](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12983).

However, to avoid link-only answers, the brief explanation is that a class method has a hidden argument "this" which refers to the instance of the class. In your case the instance is `controlInterrupt`.

If you are only ever going to have one instance of the class you could replace it with a namespace. Otherwise, make yourself a glue routine as described in that post.

Answer (score 0):

Member functions (here `pressInterrupt`) in C++ are special. You cannot use them where normal function is required (`atrachInterruot`). For explanations refer to any good book on C++.

In this particular case, just strip all C++ specific constructs off. They make your code neither shorter nor understandable. All the data for ISR is global anyway.

Comment: Hi Matt, could you please explain what you mean by "just strip all C++ specific constructs off"?

Comment: @TheCodeGeek Don't use class at all. As an it pro you should be able to figure out how to rewrite the code in plain C, aren't you?